# Python - Creating Deck of Cards - For Loop Error

Tags: python

I want to create a deck of cards in python using a nested for loop.  I tested the output first and received an unexpected result.

```
suit = ('Hearts','Clubs','Spades','Diamonds')
rank = ('Ace','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight','Nine','Ten','Jack','Queen','King')

for suit in suit:
    for rank in rank:
        print(rank + " of " + suit)
```

Here was the output:

```
Ace of Hearts
Two of Hearts
Three of Hearts
Four of Hearts
Five of Hearts
Six of Hearts
Seven of Hearts
Eight of Hearts
Nine of Hearts
Ten of Hearts
Jack of Hearts
Queen of Hearts
King of Hearts
K of Clubs
i of Clubs
n of Clubs
g of Clubs
g of Spades
g of Diamonds
```

See how the last 6 have a spread of the letters in "King".  I have no idea how this happened and still can't seem to fix it.

Comment: Why don't you use `itertools.product(*[rank, suit])` instead? It returns a list of tuple with (rank, suit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you did is you redefined rank in your for loop. At the first termination of the nested for loop, `rank = 'King'` because it was the very last thing in the tuple `rank` defined above. So in the second iteration of the outer for loop, rank is going to be `'King'` and python will iterate through each character of that string and use it as the rank variable.

In order to fix this, you should change the name of the two tuples of `suit` and `rank` to something different like `suits` and `ranks`. A fixed version looks like this:

```
suits = ('Hearts','Clubs','Spades','Diamonds')
ranks = ('Ace','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight','Nine','Ten','Jack','Queen','King')

for suit in suits:
    for rank in ranks:
        print(rank + " of " + suit)
```

Comment: Yep.  That did it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't name your variable in the loop the same as the collection you're iterating over:

```
suits = ('Hearts','Clubs','Spades','Diamonds')
ranks = ('Ace','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight','Nine','Ten','Jack','Queen','King')

for suit in suits:
    for rank in ranks:
        print(rank + " of " + suit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename the lists to suits instead of suit and ranks instead of rank.